# My UISearchBar moves to top (animated) --> want to disable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want implement an `UISearchBar` on my `tableView`.

**My code** (in viewDidLoad) :

```
self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.searchController.delegate = self
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
self.searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .None
self.searchController.searchBar.autocorrectionType = .No

self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
```

When I click on the `searchBar`, **this one move to top**, like it wants hide the `navigationBar`:

[image: When the searchbar is waiting]

[image: When I click in the searchbar]

*I searched on many posts for an answer but nothing works.* I want to disable this animation so that the searchBar doesn't move.

Comment: try this  self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: Thank for your answer. I tried `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None` and `self.searchController.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None`. The result is the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620339/search-bar-getting-hidden-by-navigation-bar-when-becomes-active This will help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of the `UISearchController` as being presented modally when you start searching. This would work fine if you had a usual `UINavigationController` setup, however in a more "customized" UI like yours you may run into issues like the search controller attaching to a wrong view, etc.

I would suggest not to use `UISearchController` in your case and use a separate `UISearchBar` initialised with the rest of your interface (probably in a storyboard?), and then do the search manually. Implement the `UISearchBarDelegate` and add your own `UITableView` for the search results, if you can't simply filter your content in place.

Although looks like you have a `tableView` var — you could simply add another property, similar to the one you use as a `UITableViewDataSource` and store *filtered* data there. So whenever you have something in the `UISearchBar` you simply use a *filtered* data source when reloading table view data. For instance:

```
var data: [String]
var filteredData: [String]
```

And then use `filteredData` in the `UITableViewDataSource`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredData.count
}

...
```

And then do something like this in the `UISearchBarDelegate`:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    // Filter the data you have. For instance:
    filteredData = data.filter({$0.rangeOfString(searchText).location != NSNotFound})
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I change. I use only a `searchBar` without its controller. Works perfect ! Thx

Answer (score 34):

You should be able to prevent this by setting:

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: I think so. And I do that, but that change anything

Answer (score 2):

Paste this line in your viewDidLoad of presenting controller:
`self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`