# Swift - UISearchController SearchBar Bug - False position after focusing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a ViewController with a TableView. On viewDidLoad I create a UISearchController and set the search bar in the header of this tableview. At beginning it is all normal, but if I focused the search bar and unfocused it, the searcher is in a false position. It overlaps like 10px of the first table view cell. The 2 pictures after explained it. In the first picture before touching the search bar. And in the second picture after touching and unselecting it.

[Before selecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN8Ez.jpg)

[After unselecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1spv.jpg)

Anyone have a idea, why it is happen?

Comment: Check this: [My UISearchBar moves to top (animated) --> want to disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408212/my-uisearchbar-moves-to-top-animated-want-to-disable)

Comment: @Kevinosaurio This is not my problem. It works all fine, except that after the first touch and untouching it again (It is clear what I mean?), it is not at the same position any more, rather like 10px below the origin.

Comment: No the question, the answer. You have a UISearchController that for experience I know that has problems with tableView, the answer is about that. Change UISearchController with only UISearchBar.

Comment: @Kevinosaurio Ah okey, I would like to use only the Search-Bar without the UISearchController, but the UISearchController implement this nice functions like pushing the search bar to the top at touching, the cancel button and so one. Do you know maybe a article, how to implement this functions?